# Which postgres type is better for containing tree paths, indexed string or array?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Which type of field is better for storing and querying tree metadata?
I got SQLAlchemy model/table, which I want to process with a trigger.

Here is pseudocode:

```py
class TreeElement(Base):
    id: int
    name: str
    parent_id: int = fk(id)


class Path(Base):
    id: int
    value: str | array = TreeElement(elem1), TreeElement(elem2) …
```

I build a structure for every ancestor by a trigger and recursive query on create/update and save it to Path table, write operations will be rare in production:

```
Tree:
elem1
    elem2
        elem3

Path:
1. elem1, elem2
2. elem1, elem2, elem3
```

Data to search (I check the integrity) in path, comes in a string type `"elem1, elem2, elem3"` (it's always ordered), I can store/query it as it is or I can split it.

And main question is: I want to know, which database type is optimal for reading purpose, indexed String or Array. Both can solve my task. There will be <100k rows in a tree, the branches will contain no more than a few dozen elements.

Answer (score 1):

That should be [`ltree`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html)

> This module implements a data type `ltree` for representing labels of data stored in a hierarchical tree-like structure. Extensive facilities for searching through label trees are provided.